# WPF: Condition Binding versus Property, XamlParseException using either

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers, multitrigger

I'm having trouble with a `Condition` for a `MultiTrigger`.  If I do the following:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
```

Then I get this exception:

> Condition cannot use both Property and Binding.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Condition' in markup file

However, when I do the following:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True"/>
```

Then I get this exception:

> Must specify both Property and Value for Trigger.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Condition' in markup file

What gives?  If it matters, here's the entire trigger:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ItemsControl.AlternationIndex}"
                   Value="0"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                   Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource evenSelected}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource evenSelectedBorder}" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API in this case is confusing.  `Condition` is used for two different types of multi-triggers, and the properties used are different. When using `MultiTrigger`, you will use the `Property` and `Value` properties. When using `MultiDataTrigger` (which is what you need), you specify a `Binding` and a `Value`.  So, if you just switch your code to use a `MultiDataTrigger`, you'll be good to go:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ItemsControl.AlternationIndex}"
                   Value="0"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
            AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                   Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource evenSelected}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource evenSelectedBorder}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I no longer get the `XamlParseException`, though I must not have the last `Condition` right yet, because my setters don't work anymore on enabled `ListView` items.