# Using MultiDataTrigger.Condition from the Settings class

Tags: c#, wpf, multidatatrigger

My `MultiDataTrigger` should change the properties of a `TabItem` if both values are as expected. One of the values is a `Property` from the `TabItem`, the other one is a `Properties.Settings.Default` property.

```
<!--<App xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"... -->

<DropShadowEffect x:Key="Glow.Foreground.Large" ShadowDepth="0" Color="WhiteSmoke" 
                  Opacity="1" BlurRadius="10" RenderingBias="Quality"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid Name="Panel" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border Name="ContentBorder" 
                            BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D4" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Effect="{x:Null}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Panel" 
                                    Property="Background" 
                                    Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="#FF2B579A" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                    Property="BorderThickness" 
                                    Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding 
                                           Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, 
                                           Path=EditorExtendChrome}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                            <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                    Property="Effect" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource Glow.Foreground.Large}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                    Property="Background" 
                                    Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"
                                 SourceName="Panel">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="#FF2B579A" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <!--Default Values-->
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semilight"/>
    </Style>
```

I'm [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649906/wpf-condition-binding-versus-property-xamlparseexception-using-either), yet the error "You must have a non-null value for 'Binding'" stills persists.

Answer (score 0):

The normal `Settings` class does not provide WPF-compatible property change notifications. It's *likely* that's why your code doesn't work. But without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, there is no way to know for sure.

The `Default` property will be `null` early in the execution of the program, and so without property change notifications, WPF will only have ever seen the `null` value, which of course is of no use to it.

Also note that, per the SO answer you're referencing, the `Condition` object for a `MultiDataTrigger` should specify `Binding` and not `Property`.

If the above does not address your concern, please provide a better code example and also be more specific about the error: when do you see this error, how is it reported, and what is the full stack trace for the error (if available)? Note that with a good code example, then even without direct support for property change notifications, it's possible an answer that solves your exact scenario could be provided.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the entire `Style` of the `TabItem`.